# Porque una imagen se ve distinta en ios a Android? y como lo pondría igual?

Tags: css, css3, imagen

En los modales estoy mostrando la imagen pero en Android se ve bien pero en ios falla que tendría que ponerle para que funcione bien en ambos casos?
el codigo css que uso para esto es

```
  .slider-img {
        height: 100px;
        @media (max-width: 360px) {
          height: 80px;
       }
        img {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          object-fit: cover;
        }
      }
```

Uso la etiqueta picture que es la que tiene la clase .slider-img
[image: Imagen en Android][image: Imagen en ios]

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente la falla? ¿No se muestra? ¿Se ve diferente? ¿Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: Si, seria eso, se ve diferente, en ios al parecer es mas grande y por eso se ve asi, pero en android esta bien, eso es una web

Comment: Intenta poniendo `object-fit: contain;` a la imagen para la versión movil. Por lo que muestras te la está recortando por el `object-fit: cover;`